# Performing mathematical operations with Firebase fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This function in my app is intended to get a user's best score, save it, and then get the difference between the best score and the target score:

```
const checkBestScore = () => {
  const db = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
  const targetAsInt = parseInt(db.get("target"));
  const bestScoreAsInt = parseInt(targetScoreProgress);
  const diffInt = targetAsInt - bestScoreAsInt;
  db.update({
    bestScore: targetScoreProgress,
    difference: diffInt,
  });
};
```

`target` is an already-existing field in my Firestore, and it is supposed to be an integer. `targetScoreProgress` is just the user's input for their target score. Both the fields `bestScore` and `target` are strings, and `difference` is supposed to be a number. However, running this function will always cause `difference` to appear as `NaN`.

**What am I doing wrong with my `bestScore` and `target` fields and how  do I use them to properly obtain `difference`?**

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a difference on a field value using [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) to operate this change.
But another approach is to process the difference on the client and to ensure that its value is correct, you can use Firestore Rules and do some comparisons. This does however require that you are also providing the current best score so you can calculate the difference.

```js
allow write: if request.resource.data.difference == resource.data.target - request.resource.data.bestScore;
```

I also suggest using additional [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules) to ensure values don't exceed limits and existing logic, as users can potentially inject their own values.